# Как проверить через какую страницу зашёл пользователь?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Как узнать с какой страницы попал пользователь на другую?
Есть например страница 1 и пользователь перешел при помощи неё на страницу 2, как узнать на какой страницы был пользователь?

Comment: Посмотрите какая информация находится в массиве $_SERVER, а в особенности присутствует ли элемент с ключом HTTP_REFERER в котором и находится информация о переходе с предыдущей страницы. Передача заголовка REFERER может быть ограничена, я о заголовке Referrer-Policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На чистом PHP это можно получить в глобальной переменной:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

На Laravel можно получить так:

```
Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')
```

Или через заголовок:

```
request()->headers->get('referer')
```

Answer (score 1):

В HTTP запросе содержится заголовок [Referer](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) который содержит предыдущую страницу